# Get MySQL DATE_ADD to work the same as PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, date-arithmetic

In PHP if you do:

```
$date = "2013-08-31";
$nextdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = date( "Y-m-d", $nextdate );
echo $date;
```

You get 2013-10-01   i.e. the month has rolled over since there are only 30 days in September.

In MySQL if you do:

```
UPDATE member_account SET NextBillDate = '2013-08-31'
SELECT DATE_ADD(NextBillDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM member_account
```

You get 2013-09-30   i.e. no roll-over

In Java it's the same thing:

```
GregorianCalendar oDate = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat Sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
try{oDate.setTime(Sdf.parse("2013-08-31"));} catch (Exception e) {}
String sTodayDate = Sdf.format( oDate.getTime() );

oDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
String sTodayDate2 = Sdf.format( oDate.getTime() );
```

sTodayDate2 is "2013-09-31"

Is there a way of making MySQL or Java behave the same way as PHP so it will rollover if the number of days in the month is exceeded?

Comment: If you want 31 days, write `interval 31 day`

Comment: The best option is to create the date in PHP, and pass that variable to your statement. The DATE_ADD function automatically sets it to the last day of the next month if it goes over the days. I'm not aware of any other SQL functions that would do what you need.

Comment: @Barmar - I want 1 month, not 31 days.

Comment: @Kacey - Trouble is, I don't have PHP, I want the same result as I'd get from using PHP but either in Java or MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this little Java snippet, does the trick:

```
    int oldDay = oDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    oDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

    // If the old DAY_OF_MONTH was larger than our new one, then
    // roll over to the beginning of the next month.
    if (oldDay > oDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
        oDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        oDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    String sTodayDate2 = Sdf.format( oDate.getTime() );
```